# Is it true that $\alpha \beta = \sup(F)$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$,$B$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that are nonempty and bounded above. By axiom of completeness, we know $\alpha = \sup A$ and $\beta = \sup B$ exists.

Let $$F = \{xy \text{ such that }x \in A \text{ and } y \in B\}$$

Is it true that $\alpha \beta = \sup(F)$?

Comment: You mean that $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, not elements.  

What are alpha and beta?  You haven't defined these yet.

Comment: Related to other similar question, I guess that they are sups of the two sets $A,B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $\alpha = \sup(A)$ and $\beta = \sup(B)$.

**HINT**

Consider $A = [-1,0]$ and $B = [-3,-2]$. What are $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\sup\left(\{xy \text{ such that }x \in A \text{ and } y \in B\}\right)$?

Comment: alpha = 0, beta = -2, and sup = 3? Can you prove by example here to state that it does not equal sup(F)?

Answer (score 2):

For a counterexample, take $A=B=[-2,-1]$.

Comment: apropos +1${}{}{}{}$